# Titanium ajax call does not send data to Laravel 5

Tags: ajax, laravel-5, titanium, appcelerator, titanium-alloy

I am trying to build a login into a mobile app.

I am doing this with Titanium Appcelerator and I am doing the Ajax POST Request to a method in my Laravel 5 Web Application that will handle the data to log in.

The problem:
The Mobile app sends the request.
The Laravel app receives the ajax request, BUT, the request comes empty! No data.

This is the code I use to receive the data.

```
Route::post("mobile/auth/login", function(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request){
     return json_encode($request->all());
});
```

This is the code Alloy View used for the form in Titanium Appcelerator

```
<Alloy>

<Window id="loginForm" fullscreen="true">

    <Label id="appTitle">FaztCash</Label>
    <Label id="appInstruction">Inicia sesión</Label>

    <View id="loginView" layout="vertical">
        <TextField id="inputUsername" />
        <TextField id="inputPassword" passwordMask="true" />
        <Button id="buttonLogin" onClick="performLogin" /> 
        <ActivityIndicator id="activityIndicator" />
    </View>

</Window>

</Alloy>
```

This is the Ajax call used to send the params

```
var main_domain = "http://127.0.0.1/";

Ti.API.info("Performing login process..");

// Comprobamos que los datos del formulario no estén vacios
if( !$.inputUsername.value || !$.inputPassword.value ){

    // Arrojamos alerta
    var dialog = Ti.UI.createAlertDialog({
        message: L('formMissingFields', 'Debes ingresar tu usuario y contraseña'),
        ok: 'OK',
        title: L('actionRequired', 'Acción requerida')
    }).show();

}else{

    Ti.API.info("Obteniendo CSRF...");
    var csrfHTTP = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({
        onload : function() {
            Ti.App.Properties.setString("csrf", this.responseText);
        },
        onerror:function(){
            Ti.API.info("Hubo un error");
        }
    });
    csrfHTTP.open("GET", main_domain + "getCSRF");
    csrfHTTP.send();

    Alloy.Globals.CSRF = Ti.App.Properties.getString("csrf");
    Ti.API.info("CSRFToken: " + Alloy.Globals.CSRF);

    // 

    Ti.API.info("Creating HTTP Client...");
    var loginReq = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient();

    Ti.API.info("Opening address...");
    loginReq.open("POST", main_domain + "mobile/auth/login");

    loginReq.setRequestHeader("enctype", "multipart/form-data");
    loginReq.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
    loginReq.setRequestHeader("X-CSRF-Token", Alloy.Globals.CSRF);

    Ti.API.info("Sending params...");

    var params = {
        "username": $.inputUsername.value,
        "password": $.inputPassword.value
    };
    loginReq.send(params);

    Ti.API.info("Loading form...");

    loginReq.onload = function()
    {
        Ti.API.info("Onload succeded!");

        Titanium.API.info("Response headers: " + JSON.stringify(loginReq.getResponseHeaders()));
        Titanium.API.info("Response body: " + this.responseText);

        var json = this.responseText;
        var response = JSON.parse(json);
        if (response.logged == true)
        {
            Ti.API.info("Logged in");
            //alert("Welcome " + response.name + ". Your email is: " + response.email);
        }
        else
        {
            Ti.API.info("Llamada falló: " + response.message);
            alert(response.message);
        }
    };

    loginReq.onerror = function(){
        Titanium.API.info("Response error headers: " + JSON.stringify(loginReq.getResponseHeaders()));
        Titanium.API.info("Response error body: " + JSON.stringify(this.responseText));
    };


}
```

And this is the Log when the request is done

```
[INFO] :   Performing login process..
[INFO] :   Obteniendo CSRF...
[INFO] :   CSRFToken: 7LMkXF8Dv5pfBVS4QPs2OC8FeafnY6szchpkHy1u
[INFO] :   Creating HTTP Client...
[INFO] :   Opening address...
[INFO] :   Sending params...
[INFO] :   Loading form...
[INFO] :   Onload succeded!
[INFO] :   Response headers: {"Keep-Alive":"timeout=5, max=100","Server":"Apache/2.4.16 (Unix) PHP/5.5.27","Content-Type":"text/html; charset=UTF-8","X-Powered-By":"PHP/5.5.27","Content-Length":"2","Date":"Fri, 16 Oct 2015 19:49:42 GMT","Cache-Control":"no-cache","Set-Cookie":"XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6ImtvMTdkTFFPc0thaVRpSFwvQlB6cENBPT0iLCJ2YWx1ZSI6IjZpUkhDWG9VakljZGpFekZOVG5tMEs4Zzk1TkVMNVRRNGFjT1dPNG5ZamhXN0JCRkVzZStyc2ZmTDA5eVVwakw2TkQ2cVwvZkZLTWhodU5CRDhoZFk4dz09IiwibWFjIjoiNmJkNzM1NmM2ZDBlNTUwMjE3ODVmNjJiNGMyMjJlYjBjMmQ1ZGFjMTgyNjZiOWMxMjc0ODQ5YjNiY2JmNjhiZSJ9; expires=Fri, 16-Oct-2015 21:49:44 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/, laravel_session=eyJpdiI6ImtKYktCNjZoUDVOVTJJdUNoZGxhTmc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiQ1BUbFpoWHpDV0Z5ZlVNQlVVZGY1ejdcLzR1Y3hUNm5LSzNGZGJ2REhQZ3RSWDVOQU1SSXBPOWJpZG45VWN3WW03T3JZaW5yZjhTNEE5TDZTYmllcFNBPT0iLCJtYWMiOiI0M2I4MzM5MTI4NGUzZjE0YzgzZjRhZjZmM2E2NjZlYjdlMGJmOTE2Zjg1ZDQzODRkMjlkN2VhMjcwZmY5OTNjIn0%3D; expires=Fri, 16-Oct-2015 21:49:44 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/; httponly","Connection":"Keep-Alive"}
[INFO] :   Response body: []
[INFO] :   Llamada falló: undefined
```

My thoughts:

When I was setting up the CSRF Protection for the form (mandatory on Laravel 5+) I noticed that it received the token and so on..
I think that it might be an issue with a cross domain ajax post call, but have no idea how to implement it on Titanium Appcelerator and I couldn't find any info in the Internet about this particular issue.

Thank you for your time everyone.

Comment: Replace the URLs with a http://requestb.in URL to see exactly what request is being send by Titanium.

Comment: I see two requests in your code, both seem OK. Which one is not working?

Comment: @FokkeZandbergen the second one was not working. The URLs where fine too. The reason why it was failing was that when the first request occurred the second request was very fast and the data from the first was never ready. It was fixed separating that second request into a function and then calling it in the onload callback of the first request.